# How to figure out proxy address and port number

Tags: eclipse, proxy, http-proxy, centos6.5

In lan setting "automatically detect setting" selected.In such scenario where can I get proxy address and port number. I need this information to resolve eclipse network issue. Which I am facing as maven warnings about connection issues.

Comment: What did you get in the terminal as result for `echo $http_proxy`?

Comment: sorry for late reply.. got nothing as seen below.btw its windows 7 system.
<<C:\>echo $http_proxy
$http_proxy

C:\>>

Comment: In Windows 7 (you tagged the question with _centos6.5_) try `netsh winhttp show proxy` or [see here](https://www.perfect-privacy.com/howto/http-proxy-configuration-windows-7/).

Comment: Actually centos installed thru Oracle VM box.i tried above netsh winhttp show proxy command..it says Direct Access <no proxy server>.

Comment: What shall I check in this case

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if there is a simple solution for that, but as a suggestion use Wireshark software to sniff the outgoing packets (like HTTP packets from your browser) and see the target IP/Port inside these packets.